# celery stdout/stederr logging while running under supervisor

Tags: celery, supervisord

I'm running celery worker with some concurrency level (e.g. 4) under supervisord:

```
[program:wgusf-wotwgs1.celery]
command=/home/httpd/wgusf-wotwgs1/app/bin/celery -A roles.frontend worker -c 4 -l info
directory=/home/httpd/wgusf-wotwgs1/app/src
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/httpd/wgusf-wotwgs1/logs/supervisor_celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/httpd/wgusf-wotwgs1/logs/supervisor_celery.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=3
killasgroup=true
stopsignal=QUIT
user=wgusf-wotwgs1
```

Problem is next: some part of stdout messages from worker (about successful execution of tasks/receiving tasks) are missing in logfile. But while running celery worker with the same concurrency level from shell - everything seems ok, messages are steadily appearing for all the tasks.
Any ideas how to fix this behavior?

Comment: Have you found any workaround?

Comment: I don't work on this project anymore (and AFAIK no solution was found). But as a shot - try to add option `redirect_stderr = true` or define different files for the stderr/stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because by default celery reports things to stderr instead of stdout